# Vue.js: Passing props to data to use in v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been trying to pass props to data like this, as I saw on another post:

**Child Component:**

```
props: {
  idInput:   { type: String, required: false },
  nameInput: { type: String, required: false },
},
data() {
  return {
    id: this.idInput,
    name: this.nameInput,
  }
}
```

So I can use it here:

```
<t-input v-model="name" type="text" />
```

**Parent Component:**

```
data() { return { game: {} } },
beforeCreated() { this.game = { name: "myName", id: "myID" }
```

```
<ChildComponent :name-input="game.name" :id-input="game.id" />
```

The problem is that "name" appears to be undefined, while if I do the same but changing "name" to "nameInput" it works, but I get the Vue error telling me not to use props like that. Any ideas?

Comment: At the moment of rendering `nameInput` probably still undefined. Try to use a default value for this prop.

Comment: Did it but same error, this time instead of undefined it's an empty string.

Comment: Whats the error message you get?

Comment: > Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "nameInput"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a functional example I created to demonstrate this case:

```js
const comp = Vue.component('comp', { 
  template: '#myComp',
  props: {
    idInput:   { type: String, required: false },
    nameInput: { type: String, required: false },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.idInput,
      name: this.nameInput,
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data () {
    return {
      game: {}
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.game = { name: 'myName', id: 'myID' };
  },
  components: { comp }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="myApp">
  <comp :name-input="game.name" :id-input="game.id" />
  {{game}}
</div>

<template id="myComp">
  <div>
    {{idInput}}
    <br>
    <input v-model="name" type="text" />
  </div>
</template>
```

**EDIT:**
After checking the code, I think the problem is that you're setting the `game` atrribute in the `data` of the parent component on `beforeCreated`. Set it on `created` instead.

**EDIT**
OP found another way to do it. Instead of passing props one by one, pass just 1 prop with the object and use its attributes on the `v-model`.

Comment: Hey thank you for taking your time! Unluckily I have pretty much the same and still can't find where is the error. Anyway will keep trying, thank you again.

Comment: @DavidDíaz sharing a fiddle link would be easier for others to debug your code

Comment: Would love to but I'm using some libraries and apis and don't really know how to replicate it.

Comment: @DavidDíaz do a comparison between this code and yours. Also, props shouldn't be used for ``v-model``, use the ``data``

Comment: This is the code, tried to add only relevant info. And yes, what I'm trying to do is use data instead of the prop, but the data value seems to be empty. https://gist.github.com/dd8888/d3461474eac1f8a6d8a6ee5c3b2ef77c

Comment: @DavidDíaz the problem is that you're trying to modify the ``data`` in the parent component on ``beforeCreated`` which is not possible, set it on ``created`` instead. I updated the answer.

Comment: Found a way to do it! Instead of passing props one by one, if I pass just 1 prop with the object and use it's attributes on the v-model and it works. Thank you so much for helping tho

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer as the solution or edit it with your final insights. This would help future visitors with such a problem.